# running gazebo without GUI

Tags: ros, gazebo, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to figure out how to run gazebo on roslaunch without the GUI showing up.How do I do that?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/404575/running-gazebo-without-gui/) by [distro](https://answers.ros.org/users/75936/distro/) on ROS Answers with karma: 167 on 2022-08-03

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You could pass the `gui` launch descriptor. This is how it looks in the command line for ROS2:

```
ros2 launch gazebo_ros gazebo.launch.py gui:=0
```

[This flag exists for ros1 as well](https://classic.gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_roslaunch)

---

Originally posted by [Pepis](https://answers.ros.org/users/66603/pepis/) with karma: 130 on 2022-08-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) on 2022-08-03**:
Usually parameters called similar to `headless` etc. could work too

**Comment by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) on 2022-08-06**:
@Pepis giving a ros2 answer for a ros1 question is not totally helpful. Also, the name of that argument depends on which launch file(s) the user has, so it may or may not work.